# How to: Only chosen data retrieving from DB in WebAPI2 and LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I'm using Entity Framework and WebAPI2. With EF I created a Model and generated the Model to get the code. When I'm calling the GetAll method in the browser then I'm getting the whole data structure (with relations to other entities). But I want to get only chosen data who will displayed in the view.

Here is the Code for GetAll:

```
/* Entity: QR_Name */
/* propertys: Id, fname, lname, maxAge, groupId */
// GET: api/QR_Name
public IQueryable<QR_Name> GetAllNames()
{
   return db.QR_Names;
}
```

I've another problem when I want to get only one object of the entity. This code doesn't work in the Browser. I'm getting a

Error Message:

> The number of supplied primary key values must match the number of primary key values that are defined in the entity.

ErrorType:

> "ExceptionType":"System.ArgumentException"

That's the code for Get id:

```
// GET: api/QR_Name/5
[ResponseType(typeof(QR_Name))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetNameById(int id)
{
  QR_Name name = await db.QR_Names.FindAsync(id); //Here comes the exception
  if (name == null)
  {
     return NotFound();
  }

  return Ok(name);
}
```

Comment: You pass in FindAsync only one parameter Id. It seems that primary key of your class QR_Names contains more than one column(look at database please).For example Id and Name. In this case you should path to FindAsync method array with two parameters(id and name)

Comment: @Disappointed oh yes.. I have in this entity 2 primary keys.. `Id, lname`.. How can I define this? I've tried public async `Task<IHttpActionResult> GetNameById(int id, string lname)
        {
            QR_Name name = await db.QR_Names.FindAsync(id, lname);` but it doesn't work.

Comment: try `FindAsync(new object[] { Id, lname })`

Comment: @Disappointed How can I invoke the object? When I try to invoke `.../api/qr_name/1` then nothing happened.

Comment: Did you change the signature of your GetNameById method recently ?

Comment: @Disappointed Do you mean the Route? `routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",` Do I have to change it and insert lname also? Because I have other entities also with multiple PKs but another columns

Comment: I mean that if you added lname parameter to your GetNameById  method and use it in FindAsync method, then(i suppose) it is problem with web  api routing. It is configured in your case to accept only one parameter, but you need to pass 2(id and lname). In this case look at appropriate section on asp.net site